# how to get next record with same last name

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve the next or previous record from sqlite based on the last name field in alphabetical (asc or desc) order from my data base. However, the last name is not an unique field and also I only can retrieve one record (LIMIT 1) for every query as I am using the call back mechanism of sqlite and I don't want to buffer the results for every possible result returned from the query (unless there is no other option). I also have a unique field called customerId (i.e the row id).

This is the statement that I currently use:

```
stream << "select * from customerTable where LastName >= '" << customerLastName << "' order by LastName asc limit 1";
```

I tried some other statements such as:

```
stream << "select * from customerTable where LastName >= '" << customerLastName << "' and CustomerId != " << customerId << " order by LastName asc limit 1";
```

But this one keeps flipping between 2 records with the same last name.

So I need to find a trick that would give me the next (or previous record) regardless when the last name is the same or not.

Comment: I may be missing the point here, but why not use `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: I am not familiar with distinct, I need to check that one out

Comment: the distinct parameter is sort of filtering duplicates, that is not what I want, I still want every record to be retrieved from the data base. But as I only retrieve one record at the time, I need to be able to retrieve the next record with the previous record as starting point. So, if the last name is the same, I need to be able to retrieve it or jump to the next last name if it is different from the previous last name. In my program, I am using the arrow up and down to browse through the customers stored in the data base based on last name in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2):

A far easier way to get all the unique names is by using `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
select distinct LastName from customerTable order by LastName asc
```

That'll give you all the unique names in alphabetical order.

Comment: Sorry NPE, I want to browse through all the customers in alphabetical order based on their last name and show their details (by pressing the arrow key up or down). I don't want to filter out customers with duplicate names, but the problem is in the use of LIMIT 1 in the sql statement as I use the call back function of sqlite to process the query results.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using queries with limit 1 and you still want do query all records with the same last name one after the other, then you can proceed with your second approach, even though it's kind of weird. After you queried the second record with `and CustomerId !=` you would have to query the next one with `and CustomerId not in (firstId, secondId)` and so on.

However, you really shouldn't go that way. The clean way is to prepare a statement first (also use host variables instead of string concatenation!) and then call `sqlite_step()` until you retrieved all your records.

Comment: You got the point Mike. My problem originated from an attempt to browse through records while limiting the results by one record at the time. Then I don't need to buffer the results and parse through them later on. But it is limiting me now in the case last names are the same. I will try to find a work arround.

Comment: You really should change your approach, drop the `limit` and keep the cursor open...

Comment: Problem solved, I first use the following query to see whether there is another customer with the same last name:    stream << "select * from customerTable where LastName == '" << customerLastName << "' and CustomerId > " << customerId << " order by CustomerId asc limit 1"; If that doesn't give me a new customerId, I use the following query: stream << "select * from customerTable where LastName > '" << customerLastName << "' order by LastName asc limit 1";

Comment: For finding previous records, it works similar, the only thing is that when querying previous records with a different last name, the query will give the first record found, skipping other records with the same last name. Therefore I had to add the following query: do { lastCustomerId = customerId; stream << "select * from customerTable where LastName == '" << customerLastName << "' and CustomerId > " << customerId << " order by CustomerId asc limit 1"; } while(lastCustomerId != customerId);

Comment: I replaced the query for previous records by the following one:      stream << "select * from customerTable where LastName < '" << customerLastName << "' order by LastName desc, CustomerId desc limit 1";
  No need to query again for the last record with the same last name.